# Extract json from text using SIddhi Execution Json API

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator, json-extract

I am trying to extract a valid json from text using Siddhi json Execution API. I have downloaded **siddhi-execution-json-1.1.1.jar** from wso2 store and following the example mentioned in the documentation there. But the same syntax above is not giving error of **"Syntax error in SiddhiiQl, mismatched input 'input' expecting {',',GROUP,ORDER,LIMIT....}"** . Below is my synatx:

```
@info(name='query_name') 
from transact#window.length(1)
select json:group("json",true) as groupedJSONArray
input transact2;
```

I am using the below text from transact stream :

```
data: "" {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "fr4wfwe4"
    },
    "code": "fesfsce",
    "name": "NAME1",
    "desc": "DECRIPTION",
    "transRefId": "FESFCSEFCS",
    "amount": 1000,
    "currency": "USD",
    "sender": {
        "id": "FRESGVSVDVEFE2333",
        "name": "rose",
        "phone": "123456789"
    },
    "message": "",
    "lockedBy": {},
    "activatedBy": {},
    "statusChangedAt": "",
    "linkBankTrans": null,
    "devGrp": 0,
    "requestId": "",
    "codeStatus": null,
    "codeTransRefId": null,
    "extOriginTransId": null
}
""
```

For reference , i am generating transact stream via below query:

```
@info(name = 'clean payload with replaceall')
from transactionstream1 
select str:replaceAll(payload,"\\","") as data
insert into transact;
```

I want to extract the valid json inside data:" " in WSO2 stream processor.
Is there some other extension i should use or there is some error in the way i am executing?
I need this query above: **@info(name='query_name') to work to get json from the above text**.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note here,

1. You are trying to use json:group() function, however, from [API docs](https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-execution-json/api/1.1.1/), this is not supported for v1.1.1, this is the reason for the syntax error. json:group() is an aggregate function, let's say I want to combine JSON elements to a single json every 3 events, in that case, group() can be used but not in your case. json:group() is only available in 2.x.x versions of the siddhi-execution-json, which is NOT compatible with WSO2 Stream Processor. It is compatible with siddhi runner (A fully open source offering which is focused on giving cloud-native abilities to siddhi lib natively ). The next-gen of wso2 sp.
2. From your previous question, it seemed you have extracted the json string inside the `payload` element. However, this is in string type and you need it as a JSON object to manipulate with siddhi-execution-json, that's your reason to strip backslashes using `clean payload with replace all` query. However, you can achieve this by using json:toObject

   ```
   from transactionstream1
   select json:toObject(payload) as payloadJson  
   insert into transact;
   ```

   For this, we will use Siddhi `object` data type which can contain any object to pass between queries or manipulate using extensions. Also json:toObject() is a [function extension type](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#function) which is used to transform attributes in one event.
3. After transforming the string to json object, you can use getString()/getFloat/getBool() functions to extract values from the json object

   ```
   from transact 
   select json:getString(payloadJson, '$.code') as code, 
   json:getString(payloadJson, '$.name') as name
   insert into LogStream;
   ```
4. BTW, is this MongoDB changes retrieved through Debezium?

Comment: Yes, MongoDB changes retrieved through Debezium

Comment: One more issue i am facing is , when i restart my wso2sp i start getting below error with regex, which wasn't there earlier:
"exception occurred when converting text message : java.lajava.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: Siddhi does have a CDC source, however, as of now, it doesn't support MongoDB. You can contribute to siddhi-io-cdc, then you can straightaway get the payload. https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-cdc/blob/siddhi-4.x.x/component/src/main/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/io/cdc/util/CDCSourceUtil.java#L53 is the place to add configs

Comment: can we shift to chat , stack trace is too long , won't adjust in comments?
I don't know how to enable state persistence in wso2sp?

Comment: After using json:toObject(payload) i want to extract entire valid json inside payload

Comment: sure, if it is siddhi related queries you can also use our slack channel, https://siddhi.io/community/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204098/discussion-between-rahul-anand-and-niveathika).

Comment: i have sent the stack trace in chat

Comment: You mean regex.*A="""{.*}""" for example